# Why can't I pass an array name as a pointer reference?

Tags: c++

I have this function whose purpose is to extract the first line in a C string:

```
// Extracts the first line in txt and puts it in dest
// Returns the length of dest
int get_line(char *&txt, char *&dest) {
    dest = txt;
    while (!(*txt == '\n' || *txt == '\0')) {
        txt++;
    }
    if (*txt == '\n') {
        *txt = '\0';
        txt++;
    }
    return strlen(dest);
}
```

I want it to work similarly to `std::getline`, which is why I decided to use pointer references. However, this very simple test does not compile:

```
int main() {
    char long_txt[] = "twas\n\nbrillig\nand the\n\n\nslithy";
    int ret;
    char *dest;
    while (*long_txt) {
        ret = get_line(long_txt, dest);
        printf("%d %s %s", ret, dest, long_txt);
    }
}
```

The compiler error:

```
decrypt.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
decrypt.cpp:52:24: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘char*&’ to an rvalue of type ‘char*’
   52 |         ret = get_line(long_txt, dest);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~
```

I don't understand why `long_txt` is considered an rvalue; it has a memory address, and I thought array names decay to pointers when passed as an argument.

Comment: When array decays, the resulting pointer is a temporary, it's computed on the fly and doesn't exist in memory otherwise. That's why it's an rvalue.

Comment: I think you should use char *txt instead of char *&txt in your get_line function.

Comment: From a practicality point of view, that entire function is quite similar to `str.substr(0, str.find('\n'))`. Switch to `string_view` and you can get a view for the rest of the string very cheaply to mimic the pointer shenanigans.

Comment: @chris unfortunately my project requirements enforce the use of C strings.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I found that declaring `long_txt` as a `char *` fixed the issue, which is funny because I had thought `char *` and `char []` to be synonymous.

Comment: In function parameters `char []` is automatically replaced with `char *`. Everywhere else they're not equivalent. Though `T []` can be implicitly converted to `T *`, so many confuse them.